# OpenERP - Field many2one, in inherited class, returning empty rows

Tags: odoo

I want to display many2one, x_categ_id, field in inherited mrp.bom class. I have defined it in _columns{..} but I am getting empty values, in the table mrp_bom, for that column, i.e. "x_categ_id". I must be missing something? Any insights are greatly appreciated.

```
class mrp_bom(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'mrp.bom'
    _name = 'mrp.bom'

    _columns = {
        'x_categ_id': fields.many2one('product.category','Item Class', 
                      required=True, change_default=True),
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually want to display? If you want to display the contents of BOM, you can just do this:

```
'product_id': fields.related('bom_id', 'product_id', type="many2one",relation='product.product', readonly=True, string="Product"),
'cost_price': fields.related('product_id', 'standard_price',type="float",digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price'), store=False, readonly=True, string="Cost Price"),
'margin': fields.float('Margin',digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Price'),required=True),
'quantity': fields.float('Quantity',digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measu  re'),readonly=True),
'bom_id': fields.many2one('mrp.bom', 'Bom', readonly=True)
```

Comment: I want to display field x_categ_id, which should contain ids from product_category table. The big picture why I need this field is in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433488/openerp-using-name-get-function-and-associated-field-definition-to-display-s).

Comment: this is just examples that already used . try to compare with this.and do it yourself. you can do it man.try..